# How can I customize the \part numbering (beyond choosing \arabic, \roman, etc.) in \documentclass{report}

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, labels, report

I am trying to customize the \part{ } numbering as it appears in my Table of Contents. Currently, when I use \part{Stuff}, it appears in the TOC as:

"I Stuff      (long whitespace)     2"

The trailing 2 in this case is the page number. I would like to change the roman I that marks part 1 to a custom label, specifically I would like it to look like this,

"Part I - Stuff (long whitespace)     2"

and for subsequent part labels to follow this formatting (Part II - , Part III - , etc.). Is this possible? It seems that an alternative would be to remove the number label entirely and simply include "Part I" in the { }, but I would need the label to be left-justified correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Renewing the `\cftpartpresnum` command provided by the `tocloft` package should do what you want.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{blindtext,tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{Part }

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \part{Part 1}
    \blinddocument
    \part{Part 2}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```